# Why does imshow jumps to a monitor that doesn't exist?

Tags: python, opencv

```
cv2.imshow('window',cv2.resize(screen,(800,600)))

Process(target=main), args=(':0.0',)).start()
```

After changing the size the window doesn't pop up, but when I click it in the taskbar it jumps between the icon and to the right and out of the screen.

Changing it back or to other sizes has no effect. Even used the undo option on pycharm, still nothing. Restarted pc to.

```
import cv2
import grabscreen

while True:
    screen = grabscreen.grab_screen(region=(0, 40, 1920, 1120))
    cv2.imshow('window', screen)
    if cv2.waitKey ( 25 ) & 0xFF == ord ( 'q' ):
         cv2.destroyAllWindows ()
         break
```

Not even running this plane code affects it.

Should also mention I have 2 monitors, I have tried all combinations 2, and just one of them, pcm, tv. also from each gpu.

Update: forcing it to run in full screen made it show, but it was terrible. I started a fresh file and wrote the program again. Now it records, but the view of the recorded screen is still jumping around. Even reinstalled opencv, could this be a gpu related problem?

Comment: Are you using `cv2.waitKey()` after calling `cv2.imshow()`? Because `waitKey()` is what actually draws the image.

Comment: Thats what i forgot on the plain example, sorry. I use that yes

Comment: What OS? How was OpenCV installed?

Comment: Windows 10 64bit, It was installed with this command: pip install --upgrade opencv-python    I run python v3.5.3  not sure how to see witch version in opencv